TsOH and 5% NaHCO3 Interaction: Unexpected Dark Green Color
Here's the brief:

I synthesized alkyl gallates (ethyl gallate, butyl gallate, and amyl gallate) using Fischer esterification.
I used TsOH instead of concentrated H2SO4 as the catalyst.
After refluxing for about 7 hours (with no gallic acid spot observed in TLC), I evaporated the excess alcohol and solvent (toluene).
Subsequently, the crude product was diluted in ethyl acetate and washed with water.
The aqueous phase was extracted three times with ethyl acetate.
The organic phases were combined and washed with a 5% NaHCO3 solution.


Here's the picture after the organic layer was washed with 5% NaHCO3:

My question:
When I washed the "combined" organic phase with a 5% NaHCO3 solution, the aqueous phase turned dark green. Why did this happen? Is it due to the TsO- salt, or is there another explanation?
I asked this because from what I've searched, I haven't found anyone mentioning TsO- turning dark green in a basic solution/NaHCO3 solution.

Repeat the reaction with a fresh batch, however if the same green color persists, it's less likely due to metal leaching from the vessel. As you haven't discovered any information regarding TsO-turning green when combined with NaHCO3, you can perhaps assume that the catalyst isn't the source of the colour. The most likely causes are product oxidation, coloured side products, or metal complexation, but again these are my estimates.

I always end up with that same green color when I wash my crude product using 5% NaHCO3 after synthesizing ethyl gallate, butyl gallate, and amyl gallate.
The picture you see above is from washing the crude product of amyl gallate, but I get that exact green color when I wash the crude products of ethyl gallate and butyl gallate too."

You know gallates are colorless? I think I told you earlier that this stuff easily oxidises? And why you want to make them so badly when you could just buy them?

Polyphenols are sufficiently electron-rich to be oxygen-sensitive, especially when deprotonated. The tosyl group has nothing to do with it - gallic acid all by itself will also darken in the presence of excess bicarb.
